# Remove Node from Arraylist (General and Specific)

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what exactly is going on with removing a node from an arraylist. My teacher gave the class a generic handout of what it does, but I'm trying to go through it to understand it.

```
public Object remove(int index)
{
     //checking bounds
     if(index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index " + index);

     Object removedData = array[index];  //save removed

     //shift array to the left
     for (int i = index+1; i < size; i++)
         array[i-1] = array[i];


    //So this for loop is supposed to go to the node after the one we are
    //trying to remove, then make the pointer from the previous point to it?

    //decrement size and return removed data
    size = size-1;
    return removedData;
}
```

Now for a specific example, on a review sheet he had a question to remove the second node.

So would I still use the index?
I wrote it to something like this:

```
public Object remove(int index)
{
     //checking bounds
     if(index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index " + index);

     Object removedData = array[index];  //save removed

     //shift array to the left
     for (int i = index3; i < size; i++)
         array[2] = array[3];
    //Here is where I changed the numbers to be specifically for the 2nd
    // node, but I'm not sure if this is right.

    //decrement size and return removed data
    size = size-1;
    return removedData;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you have to do is hardcode `index` as `1` (since arrays are zero-based, first index is 0, second is 1).

```
public Object removeSecond()
{
    int index = 1;
    // all the same code as the original method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you give me a little more explanation as to how the for loop works?

Comment: Just replace `index` with 1 every time it appears in the method. That's all. Changing the body of the `for` loop is wrong because it has to move *all* subsequent elements back by one in order to fill the vacated position, before decreasing the size of the list.

Comment: Thanks, you didn't have to be rude about it.

Comment: Sorry, I took out the rude part :)